# Как работать с программой Windows через python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем добра)

Как можно работать с программой на Windows через Python 3?
То есть отправлять этой программе клики, закрывать её и т.д. Для примера можно взять программу Putty и задачу подключиться к серверу через нее с помощью Python.

Спасибо за помощь и внимание.

Comment: В общем случае, практически все оконные процессы (программы) в Windows получают сообщения (Windows Messages) и обрабатывают их. Если же программа имеет некое API для внешнего управления (например, открывает управляющий порт, и понимает какой-то протокол), то лучше использовать более высокоуровневое решение.

Comment: Если именно Python некритично, то ИМХО проще использовать более "родную" для Windows технологию: C++, C# и т.д.

Comment: Также посмотрите здесь: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14788036/python-win32api-sendmesage

Comment: Вы уверены, что у вас вопрос именно как автоматизировать GUI программу (такую как putty), а не как команду по ssh в Питоне выполнить? Связанный вопрос: [Interact with other programs using Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14288177/4279)

Comment: Часть про отправлять клики: pyautogui или pywinauto модули. Про подключиться к серверу: fabric, paramiko модули или в худшем случае вызвать `plink.exe` (с putty распространяется), `putty.exe` команды из Питона (`subprocess` модуль) в зависимости от конкретной задачи.